# Stuck in an infinite loop, with nested if-else statements in a Java guessing program

Tags: java, if-statement, random, nested-loops, infinite-loop

/*
This application plays a Hi-Lo guessing game with numbers. The program picks a random number between 1 and 100 (inclusive), then repeatedly prompts the user to guess the number.

On each guess, the user is informed whether they are correct or if the guess is incorrect, whether it is high or low.

The program will continue accepting guesses until the user guesses correctly or chooses to quit. It will also count and report the number of guesses by the user to correctly guess the chosen number. If a guess is out of the range (1 to 100), the user will be advised to correct their guess and the guess will not be counted. At the end of each game (by quitting or a correct guess), the user will be asked to play again. If they choose to continue playing another game the program will cycle until the user chooses to stop. */

```
    System.out.println("Let's play a guessing game!");
    System.out.println("Pick a number between " + MIN + " and " + MAX +
                      " (inclusive). ");
    guess = scan.nextInt();

    while
    {
      if (guess < MIN || guess > MAX)
      {
        System.out.println("Your guess is out of range!");
        System.out.println("Pick a number between " + MIN + " and " + MAX +
                          " (inclusive). ");
      }

      count++;

      else if(guess == answer)
      {
        System.out.println("CONGRATULATIONS! The number was " + answer +
                          ". You guessed correctly in " + count + " tries!");
        System.out.println("Would you like to play again?");

        System.out.print("Type \"Y\" to play and \"N\" to quit. ");
        String play = scan.nextLine();

        if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"))
          {
          System.out.println("Game on!");
          }
        else if(play.equalsIgnoreCase("N"))
          {
          System.out.println("Thanks for playing! Good-bye.");
          return;
          }
      }
      else if (guess < answer)
          {
          System.out.println("Sorry, your guess " + guess + " is too low. "
                                    + "Try again!");
          }
      else if (guess > answer)
          {
          System.out.println("Sorry, your guess " + guess + " is too high. "
                                  + "Try again!");
          }
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: import java.util.*; 

public class guess100
{
  public static void main (String[] args)
  {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    Random generator = new Random();
    int count = 0, answer, guess = 0;
    final int MIN = 1;
    final int MAX = 100;
    answer = generator.nextInt(MAX) + MIN;

Comment: Your while does not make sense, it has no condition what so ever.

Comment: What if I put while(guess != answer)?

Comment: @LYSS What if? Try it! There's some weirdness here, though; are you sure this is your actual code? Consistent formatting goes a long way towards readability.

Comment: @LYSS, did you try to compile and run your code?  Which results did you get?